# Can we make a code runnable just for 1 time in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I want to make an **if block** code run one time after my activity starts, and then if that condition in met again while the activity is open, the if code block doesn't run, because the code had run once before.

is this possible in kotlin Jetpack Compose?

Comment: So what have you done so far?

Comment: nothing. I don't know what to do. I searched in google and didn't see anything about it!

Comment: It can be as simple as: `if (!doneBefore) { doIt(); doneBefore = true; }`. And for compose you'd better take a look at `remember`

Comment: Would you mind elaborating what's the code block you wish to run. You can do it with remember or LaunchedEffect based on what you wish to run

Comment: Hi Tracian. I want to say if may card isNotEmpity, then it be closed. but when I want to click on this car and expand it, because it is not empity, it won't open, because of that condition that I had written before. now I want to say the first condition run just once after my activity starts, and then be ignored.

Comment: this example that I said is not important, if you just show me the way about how to set it, I will implement it myself. just give me a simple code example by LaunchedEffect and remember on how to set it. thanks a lot. and it's interesting. I didn't know remember can do a thing once!

Comment: Hi momvart. thanks. an interesting example you said. also can you give a simple example about how to do this with "remember". and please write it by answering. it's better. thanks a lot

Comment: Thrician, I guess I know how to do it with "remember" now. it's like what momvart said. can you just give a simple example on how to do it with LaunchedEffect?

Answer (score 1):

If you with to do it only once your Activity is created you can use a ViewModel to hold a flag

```
class MyViewModel:ViewModel() {
  var initialized:Boolean by mutableStateOf(false)
}

@Composable
private fun MyComposable(viewModel: MyViewModel){

   if(!viewModel.initialized) {

     // Show composable or change expanded status
   }

   // or you can use LaunchedEffect
   LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
       if(!viewModel.initialized) {

       }
   }

  Button(onClick={viewModel.initialized = true) {
       Text("Button")
  }
}
```

With the snippet below your if block will only run once for this Activity unless you specifically set it to false again.

Comment: thanks. how can we do it by LaunchedEffect that you said?